# Finding the relation field of a related object in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have those two model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=250)

class ProjectUpdate(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=250)
```

Let's say that in my code I work with a Project instance, but I can't assume the object I'm working with is a project instance. I can only assume that it has one or more related models on it which I need to work on.

Now I manage to get the related class name using the related manager (project_obj.projectupdate_set). But what I need now is to know which field creates the relation. In this case this would be the "project" field on ProjectUpdate.

The only place where I find a reference to it is in the `core_filters` property of the related manager which gives me: {'project__id': 1}

I probably could use this, but it doesn't feel right.

Any idea ?

**Edit**:

Here's the properties of the RelatedManager:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', 
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', 
 '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_copy_to_model', '_db', 
 '_inherited', '_insert', '_set_creation_counter', '_update', 'add', 
 'aggregate', 'all', 'annotate', 'bulk_create', 'clear', 'complex_filter',
 'contribute_to_class', 'core_filters', 'count', 'create', 'creation_counter',
 'dates', 'db', 'db_manager', 'defer', 'distinct', 'exclude', 'exists', 
 'extra', 'filter', 'get', 'get_empty_query_set', 'get_or_create', 
 'get_prefetch_query_set', 'get_query_set', 'in_bulk', 'instance', 'iterator', 
 'latest', 'model', 'none', 'only', 'order_by', 'prefetch_related', 'raw',
 'remove', 'reverse', 'select_for_update', 'select_related', 'update', 'using',
 'values', 'values_list']
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to add the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in:

```
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='project')
```

And then `project_obj.project` leaves no wonder on which of the ProjectUpdate's field is related to. So generally add a `related_name` that has the same name as that of the field.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using django 1.4 .. but I get this: AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'query_field_name'. I've edited my post to add the dir() of the RelatedManager.. (too long for comment)

Comment: The answer is wrong. My answer only applies for m2m relationships.